# How to pass username through an href in a flask app?

Tags: python, html, web, flask

In the code below, there are 2 possible ways. If the user is logged in, he has cookie stored which will be checked and voila, a different html will appear for him. However, I want to pass username through a link from previous page.

```
@app.route("/doc")
def doc(username=None):
    print(username)              #shows None
    if username is not None:
        if verify_token(request.cookies['customCookie'+username], username):
            return render_template("doc.html", username=username)
        else:
            return redirect(url_for("login", msg="Session expired. Please login again"))
    return render_template("doc.html", username = username)
```

Below is the html link to the above route function in flask. The username printed above is always None despite the browser bar showing ___/doc?username=maman

```
<a href ="{{url_for('doc', username=username)}}">Documentation</a>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Before answering your question, are you using flask-login?

Comment: Do: `username = request.args.get('username')`

Comment: Nope, not using flask-login

Comment: Thanks, @mechanical_meat

Comment: @caissalover: you're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the parameters in a wrong way. This would work:

```
@app.route("/doc")
def doc():
    username = request.args.get('username')
    print(username)              
    if username is not None:
    ...
```